# Passing a Python union type parameter to a function that expects a non-union type

Tags: python, types, mypy

I have a data type that, because of where the data comes from, has to be flexible. It is a mapping from a string into either a string, an int, or a list of strings. However, when I run the code through the mypy type checker I get an error.

Here is an example of the code and the result of running it through `mypy`:

```
AttributeDict = dict[str, int | str | list[str]]

x: AttributeDict = {"a": 1, "b": "2", "c": ["a", "b"]}

def my_func(arg1: list[str]) -> None:
    print(arg1)

my_func(x["c"])
```

The error:

```
error: Argument 1 to "my_func" has incompatible type "int | str | list[str]"; expected "list[str]"  [arg-type]
```

I would have thought that the type being a union of three types the type-checker would not complain, but it does. How do I annotate the function definition so that the type checker is happy with this?

Comment: `arg1: int | str | list[str]`

Comment: Think about it, you are annotating that function argument as accepting **only** a list of strings, but you provide something that *might* be a `int`, a `str`, or a list of strings... of course the type checker wouldn't accept it. It is not type safe

Comment: anyway, the best way to handle this would require something more than a toy example. Your function just *prints the argument* so as it stands, you could just annotate it wiht `arg1: object` and it *would work*, but probably, you need to *actually use the parameter in some way*. For example, you may need to *iterate over it*, or use list methods / operators.

Comment: For primitive and other non-generic types you can usually narrow with `assert isinstance(value, SomeType)` to resolve union to one of its members. For more complicated types it's more difficult (probably a job for `typing.TypeGuard` or just `cast` to express "trust me, I'm sure"). Finally, in your toy example `AttributeDict` can be a `typing.TypedDict` to declare types for every key - then `x['c']` will be statically known to be of proper type.